# if-statement trouble - make code smaller

Tags: c#, if-statement

I want to make this code smaller

```
if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == ',' || e.KeyChar == '/' || e.KeyChar == ';' || e.KeyChar == '<' || e.KeyChar == '>')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

But I Don't Know How ... Please Help

Thanks

Comment: try to use regular expression.

Comment: another hint [.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Kumar: any argued reason to use regexes here? or it is just because nothing to say else?

Comment: Im Newbie c# programer " please explain More. "

Comment: Thanks To All Ppl that answered Me ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As someone hinted in a comment, you can use `Contains`.

```
char[] allowable = new [] { ',', '/', ';', '<', '>' };

if (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || allowable.Contains(e.KeyChar))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

You'd probably want to make that array `static readonly` in the parent class.

As Dennis pointed out in a comment below, a good alternative to all this might be:

```
char[] allowable = new [] { ',', '/', ';', '<', '>' };

e.Handled = char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || allowable.Contains(e.KeyChar);
```

That's definitely shorter, but it's good to note that these are not exactly synonymous. But they would be functionally equivalent, assuming you don't have preceding conditions that set `e.Handled` without calling `return`.

Comment: Or even shorter: `e.Handled = char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || allowable.Contains(e.KeyChar)`.

Comment: @Dennis True, assuming this is (as is probably fair) a complete example. It's also possible that there were preceding conditions that set `e.Handled = true` and for one reason or another, didn't `return`. But yes, in a significant majority of cases, that would be preferable. Good point.

Comment: hmm what about `e.Handled = char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || ",/;<>".Contains(e.KeyChar);`? just one line

Comment: @bansi There's certainly nothing wrong with that, but I'm not sure it really benefits anyone either. I consider the way I wrote it to be more maintainable and readable, but yes, if I was doing a [codegolf.se] challenge, I would certainly do something more like that.

Comment: @MatthewHaugen Just because OP wanted smaller code! anyhow is is a +1 from me for the nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

2 lines?

```
char[] allowableChars = new [] { ',', '/', ';', '<', '>' };
e.handled = (char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || allowableChars.Contains(e.KeyChar));
```